# How can you change the background color of a mdl button?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Is there a way to change the background color of a FAB button from the framework of getmdl.io?
I've already tried to add one more classname to button and change background-color but it doesn't work.

Comment: You should be able to simply add a color class (Such as `.mdl-color--amber-900`) and it will overwrite the existing background color - could you provide some code example of what you are attempting?

Comment: Your classname needs to be after the mdl classname, if dont work, try adding " !important " after the css config, without the code its hard to tell whats is wrong

Comment: add `background-color: colorName !important;` to your class/id of that button

Comment: @Skully thank you this helped me. I just wanted to easily change the color of a button, that was all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can recolour a button by simply adding a color class to the list, this overwrites the existing color and uses the one you provide.

For example, a regular FAB button:

```html
<!-- Colored FAB button -->
<button class="mdl-button mdl-js-button mdl-button--fab mdl-button--colored">
  <i class="material-icons">Some Text Here</i>
</button>
```

We can insert the color `.mdl-color--amber-900` by adding it to the class list:

```html
<button class="mdl-button mdl-js-button mdl-button--fab mdl-button--colored mdl-color--amber-900">
  <i class="material-icons">Some Text Here</i>
</button>
```